# Function generating $n$ copies of $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions

I need a function that, starting at $0$ or $1$, gives the sequence $$1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5...$$
In other words, has $n$ copies of $n$. What is the simplest such function, hopefully non-piecewise?

Comment: First thing that comes to mind is the [triangular numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) ...

Comment: [OEIS seq A002024](https://oeis.org/A002024)

Answer (score 1):

$$f(n) = \left\lfloor \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{2n}  \right\rfloor$$

Or, if you let $[x]$ be the nearest integer to $x$ it simplifies to $f(n) = [\sqrt{2n}]$.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved if you gave an explanation how to find this result or why this result works. A link to such would also be a good.

Answer (score 1):

The end of the run of $n$ is $T_n$, the $n^{th}$ [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number).  $T_n=\frac 12n(n+1)$  You want to invert this relationship.  Given $k$, the position in the list, you want to find the $n$ that has $T_{n-1} \lt k \le T_n$.   That is $n=\lceil \frac 12(1+\sqrt{8k+1})\rceil$

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile, the reason that the rounding will never be ambiguous is that, if we ever had (positive integer) $n$ and integer $w$ with
$$ \sqrt {2n} = w + \frac{1}{2} \; ,  $$
we would then have
$$  2n = w^2 + w + \frac{1}{4} $$
which is impossible because $1/4$ is not an integer